# Why are my Links and NavLinks not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use `react-router` and for some reason I'm having the following warning:

```
The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible.
```

This is my App.js component:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import About from './components/About';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path='about' element={<About/>}/>
          <Route path='contact' element={<Contact/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my Navbar.js component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className='ui raised very padded segment'>
      <a className='ui teal inverted segment' href="">Mateo</a>
      <div className='ui right floated header'>
        <button className='ui button'>
          <Link to="/"></Link>
          Home
        </button>
        <button className='ui button'>
          <NavLink to="/About"></NavLink>
          About
        </button>
        <button className='ui button'>
          <NavLink to="/contact"></NavLink>
          Contact
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

For some reasons my links aren't changing my url when I click on the different buttons. But if I change my URL manually the content of my page changes accordingly to the url I inserted manually.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `Link` and `NavLink` components and not that raw anchor tag above the links?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, im sure. I deleted the first 'a' tag and the warning doesn´t appear any more, but it still doesn´t change my URL as i click in the different links.

Comment: Just out of curiosity are any of these `button` elements within a `form` element? Is this the complete reproducible [mcve]? If possible could you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: No, these are not part of a form. I never used sandbox but i´ll try. @DrewReese

Comment: I see what the issue is now after formatting the code to be more readable. The link tags are empty so there is nothing to click on. In effect you are clicking the buttons and not the links. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Your **NavBar** **Component** Always write between the navLinks otherwise Link won't work.. see in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lumiere-e6o5c3?file=/src/Navbar.js)

```
import React from 'react'

import {Link, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    
        <nav className='ui raised very padded segment'>
            <a className='ui teal inverted segment' href="">Mateo</a>
            <div className='ui right floated header'>
                <button className='ui button'><Link to="/">Home</Link></button>
                <button className='ui button'><NavLink to="/About">About</NavLink></button>
                <button className='ui button'><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```